# Xamarin Form App File Creation Error

Tags: file, xamarin

I have an Xamarin Form App with two page,  I created a folder on the first page and I can create a file on this page without problem. But when I try to create a file on the second page I get the following error: Could not find a part of the path .....

Comment: Can you provide some code examples?